# How to update the nested form attributes of only the current_user in rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested-forms

I have a 'User', 'Task' and 'Comment' model in my rails 6 app. The User model is defined using devise for authentication. User has_many comments and has_many tasks and Task has_many comments.
I have a nested form for 'Task' which accepts_nested_attributes_for 'Comment'. Something like this:

```
<%= form_with model: @task do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field(:name) %>
  <br><br>
  
  <%= form.fields_for :comments do |c| %>
    <%= render('comment_fields', f: c) %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_association('Add comment', f, :comments) %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The '_comment_fields.html.erb' file looks like this:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.text_area(:body) %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association('Remove comment', f) %>
</div>
```

The above two forms are just a minimum version of the original code as I am using them only for reference here.
Now, suppose a user named 'user1' added a task named 'task1' using the task form in the database and also added some comments using the nested form for comments.
What I want is if some other user  named 'user2' tries to edit the task 'task1' then he/she should be able to add and edit only his comments with this form and can only edit the task name and 'user2' should not be able to edit or remove someone else's comments but only his. How would we go about doing this for a nested form.

We can have this functionality in some normal form like:

```
<% if @task.user.id == current_user.id %>
  <%= f.text_field(:name) %>
<% end %>
```

The above code will only show the text_field when the current model's user_id matches the current signed in user's id but I don't know how to do this in f.fields_for because we don't have a variable like @task in a nested form.

Comment: I removed the apache-cocoon tag. Its completely unrelated to the Cocoon gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the object wrapped by a [form builder instance](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html) through the `object` attribute:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.text_area(:body) %>
  <% if f.object.user == current_user %>
    <%= link_to_remove_association('Remove comment', f) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

However I wouldn't really encourage you to reinvent the [authorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization) wheel. The [Pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) or [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) gems are the most popular choices to avoid spreading and duplicating the authentication logic all over your views and controllers.

With Pundit you would do:

```
class CommentPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def destroy?
    record.user == user
  end
end
```

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.text_area(:body) %>
  <% if policy(f.object).destroy? %>
    <%= link_to_remove_association('Remove comment', f) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The equivilent with CanCanCan is:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :destroy, Comment, user: user
  end
end
```

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.text_area(:body) %>
  <% if can?(:destroy, f.object) %>
    <%= link_to_remove_association('Remove comment', f) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Out of the two I would really recommend learning Pundit. Its a bit more daunting at first since its just OOP but CanCanCan's DSL is a royal pain in the ass once you need to do anything even slightly complex.